# Why does Dart wrap process arguments in quotes where C# does not?

Tags: c#, windows, dart, command-line

I'm porting some C# code to Dart on Windows and just wasted a couple of hours on a frustrating difference in how Dart passes command line arguments through to the process.

Here's a portion of the C# code being ported, which executes just fine:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\inkscape.exe", "--file=\"C:\\Users\\Kent\\test.svg\" --export-png=\"C:\\Users\\Kent\\test.png\" --export-width=100 --export-area-page")
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
};

var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
process.WaitForExit();

if (process.ExitCode != 0)
{
    var stdout = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    var stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(stdout);
    Console.WriteLine(stderr);
}
```

Running this correctly produces an output PNG file. However, the Dart equivalent does not:

```dart
final inkscapeResult = await Process.run(
  r'C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe',
  [
    '--file="C:\\Users\\Kent\\test.svg"',
    '--export-png="C:\\Users\\Kent\\test.png"',
    '--export-width=100',
    '--export-area-page',
  ],
);
final exitCode = inkscapeResult.exitCode;

if (exitCode != 0) {
  writeError(inkscapeResult.stdout);
  writeError(inkscapeResult.stderr);
}
```

Instead, the process exits with code `1` and the program outputs:

```
** (inkscape.exe:5604): WARNING **: 17:30:09.785: Can't open file: "C:\Users\Kent\test.svg" (doesn't exist)

** (inkscape.exe:5604): WARNING **: 17:30:09.785: Can't open file: "C:\Users\Kent\test.svg" (doesn't exist)

** (inkscape.exe:5604): WARNING **: 17:30:09.785: Specified document "C:\Users\Kent\test.svg" cannot be opened (does not exist or not a valid SVG file)
```

It is pretty well-known that Inkscape is a bit finicky when it comes to executing on the command line, but the advice I've read is to simply pass in full paths, which I am doing.

I found that if I eschew arguments, it works:

```dart
final inkscapeResult = await Process.run(
  r'C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe --file="C:\\Users\\Kent\\test.svg" --export-png="C:\\Users\\Kent\\test.png" --export-width=100 --export-area-page',
  [],
);
```

So I inferred that Dart must be doing something with the arguments that Inkscape does not like. I managed to catch it in the act using Process Explorer and it has the following command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" "--file=\"C:\Users\Kent\test.svg\"" "--export-png=\"C:\Users\Kent\test.png\"" --export-width=100 --export-area-page
```

If I run this directly from the command line, I get no output but the image also does not get generated, so presumably it's failing in the same fashion. Compare this with the command line produced by the C# code:

```
"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" --file="C:\Users\Kent\test.svg" --export-png="C:\Users\Kent\test.png" --export-width=100 --export-area-page
```

Dart is wrapping each individual argument with quotes, where C# is not (though C#'s API does not even separate individual arguments). This is somehow breaking Inkscape's parser.

Who is in the wrong here? Me, Dart, C#, or Inkscape?

Comment: Seems like Dart is adding the surrounding double quotes only when the command line argument itself contains double quotes. For example this works: `'--file=C:\\Users\\Kent\\test.svg'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to split the argument name and the argument value like that:

```
  final inkscapeResult = await Process.run(r'C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe', [
    '--file', 'C:\\Users\\Kent\\test.svg',
    '--export-png', 'C:\\Users\\Kent\\test.png',
    '--export-width', '100',
    '--export-area-page',
  ]);
```

That way you don't have to worry about escaping or quoting arguments.

Comment: This won't give the correct command line though, it's missing the `=` for a start.

Comment: It seems to work though. Generally a program will accept both way of specifying arguments.

Comment: Whilst this works in this case (thanks, have an upvote), I don't find it a very satisfying answer. It seems somewhat coincidental that Inkscape accepts both forms, and certainly its documentation encourages the first form with `=`.

Comment: I have written a lot of dart scripts to interact with other programs (imagemagick, sox, ffmpeg, fontforge...) I have never seen one that doesn't work with the "space-separated" form.